# Do I need to include the information (Pvalue) of confounders in the final table?

Tags: regression, reporting, confounding

I was wondering if I need to provide a regression table including the estimation of all main varibales + confounders? Can I just present the final result (coefficeint and pvalues) of the main variables after adjustment?

Comment: Include where? In a study report? In an abstract? In a full peer-reviewed manuscript? On a slide?

Comment: @ Alex, Thanks for the reply. For the  manuscript. Can I just report the pvalue and the coeffient of the main variables? Or I need to provide the full table including all info regarding main and confounders>

Comment: In articles, these tables are normally never provided. But the correspondent author is expected to provide them if requested by the journal reviewers or readers.

Comment: This paper might be relevant to read: Daniel Westreich, Sander Greenland, The Table 2 Fallacy: Presenting and Interpreting Confounder and Modifier Coefficients, American Journal of Epidemiology, Volume 177, Issue 4, 15 February 2013, Pages 292–298, https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kws412